# Не работает 'insertBefore' в js. Help!

Tags: javascript

Изучаю javascript, скачал с торрентов  видеоуроки и завис на одной домашке.
В задании надо упорядочить элементы меню и удалить блок "adv". 
Прошу помощи с пояснением для чайников, потому что я за 2 дня перерыл все форумы и справочники и так и не решил эту проблему.[весь код в песочнице][1] Заранее спасибо![1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZRrNfxS5TJlBdDqUNpH0?p=preview

```js
var nav = document.getElementsByTagName('nav'),
    menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu'),
    item = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
item[2].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
document.menu.insertBefore(item[2], item[1]);



var column = document.getElementsByClassName('column'),
    title = document.getElementsByClassName('title'),
    adv = document.getElementsByClassName('adv');
document.column.removeChild(title);
document.column.removeChild(adv);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    height: 670px;
    background: url(../img/apple.jpg) center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 180px;
    font-family: "Cuprum"
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-end;
}


.item {
    color: #fff;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px  rgba(256,256,256,.4);
}


.column {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: -4px;
    min-height: 500px; 
}
.title {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
}
.adv {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #dff;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.prompt {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .7);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Apple</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
     <nav>
       <ul class="menu">
         <li class="item">Первый пункт</li>
         <li class="item">Третий пункт</li>
         <li class="item">Второй пункт</li>
         <li class="item">Четвертый пункт</li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
   </header>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="title" id="title"> 
        Мы продаем только технику Apple
      </div>
      <div class="adv">
        Это назойливая реклама, которую нужно удалить
      </div>
      <div class="prompt" id="prompt">
      </div>
    </div>

 <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Возможно,Ваш код и удалил бы что-нибудь, но Вы местами забываете, что метод `getElementByClassName` возвращает массив элементов. https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom

Answer (score 0):

Вы собственно не понимаете какие методы к каким объектам можно применять отсюда и бардак.
У ассоциативного объекта/массива или как говорят псевдомассива HTMLCollection нет методов insertBefore и.т.д .
У вас же column,title,dev и.т.д это псевдомассивы HTMLCollection.
Учите азы, что такое объект/массив, какие они бывают, свойства и методы различных объектов.

```js
var nav = document.getElementsByTagName('nav'),
    menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu'),
    item = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
    
item[2].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
menu[0].insertBefore(item[2], item[1]);



var column = document.getElementsByClassName('column'),
    title = document.getElementsByClassName('title'),
    adv = document.getElementsByClassName('adv');
    
column[1].removeChild(adv[0]);
column[1].removeChild(title[0])
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    height: 670px;
    background: url(../img/apple.jpg) center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 180px;
    font-family: "Cuprum"
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-end;
}


.item {
    color: #fff;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px  rgba(256,256,256,.4);
}


.column {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: -4px;
    min-height: 500px; 
}
.title {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
}
.adv {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #dff;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.prompt {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .7);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Apple</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
     <nav>
       <ul class="menu">
         <li class="item">Первый пункт</li>
         <li class="item">Третий пункт</li>
         <li class="item">Второй пункт</li>
         <li class="item">Четвертый пункт</li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
   </header>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="title" id="title"> 
        Мы продаем только технику Apple
      </div>
      <div class="adv">
        Это назойливая реклама, которую нужно удалить
      </div>
      <div class="prompt" id="prompt">
      </div>
    </div>

 <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```